# azure container instance : deployment successful - IP address doesn't not respond

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I have a ML container image which is accessible at - http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model on my local system.

After I push it to an Azure Container Registry, I create Azure Container Instance (set port - 8501). its deployment is successful, and IP address is generated.

My issue is when i try to access the IP address, it does not respond.

I have tried:
http://40.12.10.13/
http://40.12.10.13:8501
http://40.12.10.13:8501/v1/models/my_model

It's a TensorFlow serving image https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker
Below is the Docker file code -

```
ARG TF_SERVING_VERSION=latest
ARG TF_SERVING_BUILD_IMAGE=tensorflow/serving:${TF_SERVING_VERSION}-devel

FROM ${TF_SERVING_BUILD_IMAGE} as build_image
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH=master
ARG TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_COMMIT=head

LABEL maintainer="gvasudevan@google.com"
LABEL tensorflow_serving_github_branchtag=${TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH}
LABEL tensorflow_serving_github_commit=${TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_COMMIT}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install TF Serving pkg
COPY --from=build_image /usr/local/bin/tensorflow_model_server /usr/bin/tensorflow_model_server

# Expose ports
# gRPC
EXPOSE 8500

# REST
EXPOSE 8501

# Set where models should be stored in the container
ENV MODEL_BASE_PATH=/models
RUN mkdir -p ${MODEL_BASE_PATH}

# The only required piece is the model name in order to differentiate endpoints
ENV MODEL_NAME=model

# Create a script that runs the model server so we can use environment variables
# while also passing in arguments from the docker command line
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash \n\n\
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
--model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME} \
"$@"' > /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh \
&& chmod +x /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: can you share how you create the ACI instance?

Comment: these were the parameters passed while creating ACI in this case. OS Type = Linux , Port =8501 , cpu core =4 , memory =8 .

Comment: where do you pass those? what command do you use or something

Comment: Azure portal, instructions are at  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal

Comment: I am exposing the same port 8501 in the container and ACI as advised in the document. not sure why IP is not responding,

Comment: pretty much impossible to tell given these details, can you show your dockerfile?

Comment: updated docker file in description. I haven't made any changes of my own into it, I use the standard serving image, copy my model into it and trying to host its Instance on ACI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197513/discussion-between-ashwini-prakash-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: @4c74356b41    I figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: either delete this question or post an answer, please